# String not outputting in a foreach loop

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to react and I am trying to create a foreach loop. However when its outputted in the browser it shows like this

```
[object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

Not sure why its happening

Below is my code any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
const Book =({book_info})=> {



    let output = "";


    book_info.forEach(book => {
        //console.log(book.title);

        output += <h1> {book.title}</h1>

    });

    console.log(output);
    return <section>

        {output}
    </section>

};

const Library = () => {
    let book_info = [{title:"The sun also rises", author:"Ernest Hemigway",pages: 260},{title:"The sun also rises", author:"Ernest Hemigway",pages: 260},{title:"The sun also rises", author:"Ernest Hemigway",pages: 260}];
    return (

        <div>
           <Book book_info={book_info}/>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
output += <h1> {book.title}</h1>
```

It is effectively looping through `book_info` and converting the `h1` react component to a string which is `[object Object]`.

What you want to do is:

```
return <section>
  {book_info.map(book => <h1>{book.title}</h1>)}
</section>
```

This loops through `book_info` and *maps* the react element as children to the `<section>` element.

Comment: Ohh okay got it. I was just a little confused cause .map() says it returns an array.... but i am guessing cause we are using JSX it returns back a string to the browser...

Comment: No, you are correct, it does return an array. However, in this case it returns an array react elements, not string. Have a look at [React Without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) for reference.